# Keyboard shortcuts for moving tabs in and out of tab groups

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, keyboard-shortcuts

I had been struggling with the fact that tab groups have no native keyboard shortcut functionality as neatly outlined by Zack Steiger in this locked Google Chrome community post: [Tab Groups are in need of keyboard accessibility](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/82128623/tab-groups-are-in-need-of-keyboard-accessibility?hl=en)

Desired keyboard functionality includes but is not limited to the following:

1. Collapse/expand current tab group
2. Collapse/expand tab group by tab number (currently cmd+1, cmd+2, etc
   will access first and 2nd open tab but skip over tab groups
   entirely)
3. Move tab into or out of adjacent tab group
4. Create new tab group with current tab
5. Move into closed tab groups with the "move tab" shortcut. Cmd+option+left/right moves from tab to tab natively, but if a tab group is closed, it is skipped entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As I was researching solutions for these desired actions, I realized that the Chrome extension [Rearrange Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rearrange-tabs/ccnnhhnmpoffieppjjkhdakcoejcpbga) (which I had installed but forgot which keyboard shortcuts I had assigned) takes care of #3 above.

The extension allows you to select keyboard shortcuts for moving tabs left, right, or to the beginning or end of the tab list. When moving tabs left or right with a tab group adjacent, the shortcut moves the tab out of the current tab group and/or into the adjacent tab group – even if the tab group is closed.

I was pleasantly surprised to see that the shortcut to move the tab to the very beginning or very end of the tab list did not inject it into a tab group in the first or last position. Others may want a different behavior, but this is preferred for me.

For #4 above, I recently learned of Mac's "App shortcuts" in the keyboard shortcut settings. This allows you to set an app-specific keyboard shortcut for any menu item. For a new tab group, create the menu command "Tab->Group Tab" (no spaces around the arrow, and watch your capitalization) and select your keyboard shortcut.

#5 is the biggest miss for me personally.

Update for #5: The [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck) extension allows you to set a keyboard shortcut for next/previous tab, and it will open a closed tab group to allow traversal. Grateful for this, though I'm quickly realizing I will not use this shortcut in its current iteration. I'd want the previous tab group to collapse when I leave it so that only one group stays open at a time. It quickly turns into a mess of tabs since all the groups stay open.